# Python - NLP not able to print file text

Tags: python, nltk

I am playing around with [Natural Language Toolkit](https://www.nltk.org/) for python and I am trying to print a file text in a terminal, this is what I did

```
import io
import nltk
from nltk.text import Text

with io.open("job.txt", "+r", encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
     my_unicode_string = my_file.read()

job = Text(my_unicode_string)
print(job)
```

and the output i seen in terminal is as following

```
<Text: * W o r l d   T...>
```

What do I need to do to print the text?

Another thing I noticed is if I do

```
print(job.count('language'))
```

The output I get is `0` which is totally wrong as I am pretty sure this word exist in the text file.

I will really appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this because your `my_unicode_string` is a string, when you run `Text(my_unicode_string)`, you operate on a list of all **characters** of the string, but what you expect is operating on a list of all **words** of the string. Try replace `my_unicode_string = my_file.read()` to `my_unicode_string = my_file.read().split(" ")`.

Comment: Thanks this does help however i noticed that if i do print(job.count('language')) i get the outnow that says 2 which is still wrong as i know for sure that this word appears 13 times in the document. Any idea now why this is happening?

Comment: @Saadia, sorry I have no idea of this. Can you show some example words of `job.txt`?